# Ampersand not working in :before in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I'm building spritesheet buttons, something like this:

```
<a class="Button one"></a>
<a class="Button two"></a>
```

With style:

```
a {
    // Add basic background and styling
    background: transparent url("images/background_image.png") no-repeat;

    // Add icon on top
    &:before {        
        content: '';
        display: block;

        //....
        background: transparent url("images/icons.png") no-repeat;

        // (1)
        &.one { @include tile(165px, 0, 0) }
        &.two { @include tile(165px, 1, 0) }
    }

    // (2)
    &.one:before { @include tile(165px, 0, 0) }
    &.two:before { @include tile(165px, 1, 0) }
}
```

Now I want to add the variant styles, but `(1)` does not work, only `(2)`. Is there no way to avoid repeating the `:before`?

Comment: Did you try looking at the compiled CSS?  Does it validate (no really, check the "Valid CSS information")?

Comment: Of course it produces garbage with `(1)`, that's why I'm asking how to do it better. No need to downvote

Comment: @cimmanon how else would you describe that my property is not applied to my element? That's the definition of "not working" in my dictionary

Comment: There's a difference between "it generates error XYZ when I try to compile it" vs "it generates invalid CSS" vs "it formats my hard drive".  But hey, you're right "doesn't work" is a hell of a lot more useful than any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the compiled CSS, you'd get something like this:

```
a:before.one { /* ... */ }
```

CSS pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` cannot have classes. If you want to make it shorter, one option would be to combine the classes:

```
a {
    &.one, &.two {
        &:before { @include tile(165px, 0, 0) }
    }
}
```

But since you want to use different values for the mixin, I think #2 is the cleanest way to go.